# OpenDDS and OpenSplice interoperability

Tags: configuration, interop, data-distribution-service, opensplice, opendds

I have two programs, one using **OpenSplice 6.7.1** and the other using **OpenDDS 3.10.**

They are both using **RTPS** as protocol, the same **domain id** and the **destination port** (I verified using wireshark).

The problem is that they are not communicating.

I don't know if I am doing anything wrong with the config... I am using the basic config for OpenDDS with **RTPS** and for OpenSplice I used the provided ospl.xml after changing the domain ID.

Here are my config files.
**For OpenDDS:**

```
[common]
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=$file
DCPSDefaultDiscovery=DEFAULT_RTPS
[transport/the_rtps_transport]
transport_type=rtps_udp
```

**For OpenSplice:**

```
<OpenSplice>
    <Domain>
        <Name>ospl_sp_ddsi</Name>
        <Id>223</Id>
        <SingleProcess>true</SingleProcess>
        <Description>Stand-alone 'single-process' deployment and standard DDSI networking.</Description>
        <Service name="ddsi2">
            <Command>ddsi2</Command>
        </Service>
        <Service name="durability">
            <Command>durability</Command>
        </Service>
        <Service name="cmsoap">
            <Command>cmsoap</Command>
        </Service>
    </Domain>
    <DDSI2Service name="ddsi2">
        <General>
            <NetworkInterfaceAddress>AUTO</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
            <AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
            <EnableMulticastLoopback>true</EnableMulticastLoopback>
            <CoexistWithNativeNetworking>false</CoexistWithNativeNetworking>
        </General>
        <Compatibility>
            <!-- see the release notes and/or the OpenSplice configurator on DDSI interoperability -->
            <StandardsConformance>lax</StandardsConformance>
            <!-- the following one is necessary only for TwinOaks CoreDX DDS compatibility -->
            <!-- <ExplicitlyPublishQosSetToDefault>true</ExplicitlyPublishQosSetToDefault> -->
        </Compatibility>
    </DDSI2Service>
    <DurabilityService name="durability">
        <Network>
            <Alignment>
                <TimeAlignment>false</TimeAlignment>
                <RequestCombinePeriod>
                    <Initial>2.5</Initial>
                    <Operational>0.1</Operational>
                </RequestCombinePeriod>
            </Alignment>
            <WaitForAttachment maxWaitCount="100">
                <ServiceName>ddsi2</ServiceName>
            </WaitForAttachment>
        </Network>
        <NameSpaces>
            <NameSpace name="defaultNamespace">
                <Partition>*</Partition>
            </NameSpace>
            <Policy alignee="Initial" aligner="true" durability="Durable" nameSpace="defaultNamespace"/>
        </NameSpaces>
    </DurabilityService>
    <TunerService name="cmsoap">
        <Server>
            <PortNr>Auto</PortNr>
        </Server>
    </TunerService>
</OpenSplice>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-vendor interoperability has been demonstrated repeatedly at OMG events but not recently, so maybe a regression has happened with/in either of the products.

Your OpenSplice configuration is (apart from domainId which should match the one used in your application where typically users use DDS::DOMAIN_ID_DEFAULT to indicate they want to use the ID as specified in the configuration as pointed to by the OSPL_URI environment variable) a proper default configuration. I'm sure you are aware that the AUTO setting of the to-be-used interface/IP-address is a potential source-of-confusion if you use multi-homed machines.

So next would be to look at both (DDSI)traces and/or wireshark captures and see if you spot DDSI wire-frames for both Vendors (1.2 for PrismTech, 1.3 for OCI).

When for instance there's no sign of vendor-1.3 being identified in OpenSplice DDSI-traces then that suggests there's still some 'fundamental' communication issues.

Note that at these OMG-events we typically used the (for us 'bundled') iShapes example on domain '0' and module-less IDL topic-type specification to verify interoperability, so it it doesn't work for your application that's something worth trying too (and check/use wireshark in combination with that example too)

I'll also keep watching the community-forum for new information on this ..

Comment: I updated my post on the forum concerning this issue. 
I modified my IDLs and made them module-less but still no interoperability. I modified the IDL of iShapes provided by OpenDDS and made it module-less and did the necessary modifications on the source files but still no interoperability between both iShapes. I added the IP address as you advised : <NetworkInterfaceAddress>10.0.2.15</NetworkInterfaceAddress>

Comment: I used wireshark to trace the packets and I noticed something interesting: OpenSplice is using the right interface to communicate, it is periodically sending 3 packets that have the same length  but when I publish my data, the publisher receives but I see nothing on wireshark ! There is no trace of the data that is sent !
When I use openDDS with openSplice, when a participant is connected openDDS starts sending HEARTBEAT packets which is a normal behavior when another participant is detected ! However the data sent and the disconnection remain not detected !